# Probot logs do not appear

Tags: typescript, probot

I'm trying to log the flow of my probot app but they do not appear in my terminal.
I've set up a boilerplate project by running `npx create-probot-app my-first-app` and choosing the `basic-ts` project.

My index.ts file looks like this -

```
import { Probot } from "probot";

export = (app: Probot) => {
  app.log.info("Yay, my app is loaded");
  app.on("issues.opened", async (context) => {
    context.log.info("momo-issue")
    const issueComment = context.issue({
      body: "Thanks for opening this issue!",
    });
    await context.octokit.issues.createComment(issueComment);
  });
};
```

The app is working as expected, opening an issue prompts the bot to create a comment, but the logs I've added are still missing.
I've restarted the server multiple times, but still can't see the logs.

Any idea what's missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs did not appear because I did not rebuild my app.
Once I've ran `yarn build` logs started showing up...